# Why is the refresh link to my captcha not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, refresh, captcha

I have a contact form (http://www.cig.earthdogpromotions.com/contact.htm) where the link to refresh the captcha does not work. I have tried it in a PHP based contact form, which works fine. This one is on an HTML contact form.
What am I missing or what should I add to make it work? Do I need any special JavaScript code? (If you give me some extra code, please explain where to put it.
No one is answering my question, so I think I will try to convert it to PHP, and iframe it into the HTML. **Any suggestions?**
Here is the codes

**HTML**

```
    <div id="contact-area">
        <br><br>
        <form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Please enter required="required" /><br><br>

            <label for="City">Phone:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="City" id="City" /><br><br>

            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Please enter Email" required="required" /><br><br>

            <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
            <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="40" id="Message"enter Message" required="required"></textarea><br><br>

            <p>
<img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' ><br>
<label for='message'>Enter the code above here :</label><br>
<input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text"><br>
<small>Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh</small>
</p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button"     />
        </form>

</div>
```

**PHP**

```
session_start();
//Settings: You can customize the captcha here
$image_width = 120;
$image_height = 40;
$characters_on_image = 6;
$font = './monofont.ttf';

//The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
//avoid confusing characters (l 1 and i for example)
$possible_letters = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
$random_dots = 0;
$random_lines = 20;
$captcha_text_color="0x142864";
$captcha_noice_color = "0x142864";

$code = '';


$i = 0;
while ($i < $characters_on_image) { 
$code .= substr($possible_letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_letters)-1), 1);
$i++;
}


$font_size = $image_height * 0.75;
$image = @imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);


/* setting the background, text and noise colours here */
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$arr_text_color = hexrgb($captcha_text_color);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_text_color['red'], 
    $arr_text_color['green'], $arr_text_color['blue']);

$arr_noice_color = hexrgb($captcha_noice_color);
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_noice_color['red'], 
    $arr_noice_color['green'], $arr_noice_color['blue']);


/* generating the dots randomly in background */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_dots; $i++ ) {
imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width),
 mt_rand(0,$image_height), 2, 3, $image_noise_color);
}


/* generating lines randomly in background of image */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_lines; $i++ ) {
imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height),
 mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height), $image_noise_color);
}


/* create a text box and add 6 letters code in it */
$textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $code); 
$x = ($image_width - $textbox[4])/2;
$y = ($image_height - $textbox[5])/2;
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $code);


/* Show captcha image in the page html page */
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');// defining the image type to be shown in browser widow
imagejpeg($image);//showing the image
imagedestroy($image);//destroying the image instance
$_SESSION['6_letters_code'] = $code;

function hexrgb ($hexstr)
{
  $int = hexdec($hexstr);

  return array("red" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x10),
           "green" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x8),
           "blue" => 0xFF & $int);
}
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more pertinent to actually post the `refreshCaptcha()` function that is called when the anchor is clicked ?

Comment: In your page, there is no `refreshCaptcha()` function defined. so it won't work anyway. And captcha `img src` attribute has `<?php ... ?>` inside its value

Comment: Okay I tried it without the <?php ... ?> reference and it still doesn't work. (I overlooked that.)

Comment: Someone please tell me what Raj Kamal means by "there is no refreshCaptcha() function defined?" I copy/pasted the code from a working PHP based contact form. It WORKS! But I put it in HTML and it doesn't. WHY????